# Insert new features into Oracle DB using PyQGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, oracle-dbms

I need to insert new objects into a specific layer that stored in Oracle database.
Firstly I set a new QgsFeature(), then set geometry and attributes. Finally perform addFeatures() action.

```
nodes_pnt = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(u'PLOTPOINT')[0]
layer = iface.activeLayer()
out_geom = layer.selectedFeatures()[0].geometry()
feature_geom = QgsFeature()
feature_geom.setFields(nodes_pnt.fields())
feature_geom.setGeometry(out_geom)
feature_geom['DESCRIPTION_'] = "new_object"
nodes_pnt.dataProvider().addFeatures([feature_geom])
```

But instead of adding new feature to the layer, QGIS throws an error like

```
SQL: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("GIS"."PLOTPOINT"."DOC_ID")
```

I tried another way without setting fields into `feature_geom`.

```
feature_geom.setGeometry(out_geom)
feature_geom.setAttributes(['test', "", "", "","","","",""])
nodes_pnt.dataProvider().addFeatures([feature_geom])
```

However I still got the same error.

I thought about direct connection to the Oracle database using `QSqlDatabase` to insert values with SQL code, but here I even did not got any connection though parameters were right.

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery
db = QSqlDatabase("QOCI")
db.setHostName("test.local:1521\oradb")
db.setPort(1521)
db.setDatabaseName("oradb")
db.setUserName("gis")
db.setPassword("gis")
db.open()
```

Here I had my `db.open` False everytime.

What can be done here?

Comment: You need to include all NOT NULL columns in your column list (at least, those without DEFAULT values).

Comment: @Vince I added all the fields and set values for them. In layer window I saw that the number of features in layer increased but geometry didn't appeared nor in table neither in mapper window.

Comment: This seems to be a new question as a comment. You should verify that the geometry exists using a SQL client like SQL*Plus , etc, then research whether it is necessary to explicitly refresh the spatial index.

Comment: Also did you commit the insert ? Something like db.commit() ?

Comment: @Vince all things are okay now. That was a side QGIS project that had some visibility filters. I was wondering why objects are not visible and that was ust because of them

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind I deal with that, look at the comment below. Anyway, all inserts in pyqgis commit automatically, probably using og `psycopg2` in this case will demand commit